# Create and execute function in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-function

I have four tables:

1. `dbo.Projects`
2. `dbo.Locations`  (id, location name)
3. `dbo.Purpose` (id, Purposename)
4. `dbo.Types` (id, typname)

I have a search criteria, this criteria is filled with data from database tables: `locations`, `purpose` and `types`.

I want to create a function that returns table with search result from `projects` dependent on other tables. I have created one but it does not do what I need:

```
 ALTER FUNCTION SearchProjects
 (
     @location nvarchar(50),
     @purpose nvarchar(50),
     @type nvarchar(50)
 )
 RETURNS TABLE
 AS
 RETURN
(
      SELECT dbo.Projects.ProjectName, dbo.Projects.Areas,           
             dbo.Projects.PaymentSystem, dbo.Projects.ReceivedDate,    
             dbo.Projects.PropertyClassification, 
             dbo.Projects.ProjectImage
      FROM dbo.Locations INNER JOIN
      INNER JOIN dbo.Projects ON dbo.Locations.ID = dbo.Projects.ID      
      INNER JOIN dbo.Purpose ON dbo.Locations.ID = dbo.Purpose.ID 
      INNER JOIN dbo.Types ON dbo.Locations.ID = dbo.Types.ID
      WHERE (Projects.ProjectName like N'%'+ @location +'%' 
         and Purpose.PurposeName = N'%'+ @purpose +'%' 
         and Types.TypeName like N'%'+ @type     +'%')
 )
 GO
 SELECT * FROM dbo.SearchProjects('',' ','');
```

I'm new to SQL SERVER so any help is appreciated.

Comment: i want to search only not save or insert record into database

Comment: Do you have an error message?

Comment: no the table return with no data i don't know if the select statement it is true or not i want to select project from projects table depend on others table

Comment: You use INNER JOINs that requires that each id has to be an entry in all four tables. If this is the case? Otherwise, use LEFT JOINs.

Comment: You need to pass some value. dont pass it as blank

Comment: yes i passed the values that already in database but the table return with no result = null

Comment: Take your select query outside and then check is it return any data

Comment: Check it without any condition. if it returns no data then you have change your join condition or check data in fyour main table is matching with other table or not

Comment: @MansiChaudhari yes it is return data when i takes the select query outside

Comment: returns two rows from projects table

Comment: `Projects.ProjectName like N'%'+ @location +'%'` - is this correct? Looks like a typo.

Comment: @IvanStarostin i think yes it is correct for Arabic text

Comment: [hashim](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6704418/hashim), I think what [Ivan Starostin](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5921826/ivan-starostin) is trying to point out is that you are comparing the `ProjectName` field in your `Projects` table to the `@location` value passed in. It seems unlikely that the location will ever match the `ProjectName`, so is this a mistake in your query?

Comment: I think we also need some clarification on your schema - could you post `CREATE TABLE` commands for the 4 tables involved, ideally with some example data from each table as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with:

```
ALTER FUNCTION SearchProjects (
    @location NVARCHAR(50),
    @purpose NVARCHAR(50),
    @type NVARCHAR(50))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    SELECT  p.ProjectName, 
            p.Areas, 
            p.PaymentSystem, 
            p.ReceivedDate,    
            p.PropertyClassification, 
            p.ProjectImage,
            l.LocationName,
            pur.PurposeName,
            t.TypeName
    FROM dbo.Projects AS p 
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Locations AS l ON p.LocationID = l.ID      
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Purposes pur ON p.PurposeID = pur.ID 
    LEFT JOIN dbo.[Types] AS t ON p.TypeID = t.ID
    WHERE UPPER(ISNULL(l.LocationName,N'')) LIKE N'%' + UPPER(@location) + '%'
    AND UPPER(ISNULL(pur.PurposeName,N'')) LIKE N'%' + UPPER(@purpose) + '%'
    AND UPPER(ISNULL(t.TypeName,N'')) LIKE N'%' + UPPER(@type) + '%'
     )
GO
```

if you want to return only Projects where **all** of the criteria are met and an empty string in an input parameter is treated as a wildcard:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.SearchProjects('','',''); -- Returns all records

SELECT * FROM dbo.SearchProjects('north','',''); -- Returns all records with LocationName containing 'north'
SELECT * FROM dbo.SearchProjects('','research',''); -- Returns all records with PurposeName containing 'research'
SELECT * FROM dbo.SearchProjects('','','closed'); -- Returns all records with TypeName containing 'closed'

SELECT * FROM dbo.SearchProjects('north','research',''); -- Returns all records with LocationName containing 'north' and PurposeName containing 'research'
```

This also removes any case-sensitivity when comparing input parameter values to field values in your tables. I would still use `LEFT JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN` just in case some project records might have faulty LocationID, PurposeID or TypeID values.

If you want to return Projects where **any** of the criteria from the input parameters are met (and not treat empty input parameters as wildcards when at least one input parameter contains a value), you could change the `AND`s in the `WHERE` clause to `OR`s and pass `NULL` for any input parameters you don't wish to specify a value for:

```
ALTER FUNCTION SearchProjects (
    @location NVARCHAR(50),
    @purpose NVARCHAR(50),
    @type NVARCHAR(50))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    SELECT  p.ProjectName, 
            p.Areas, 
            p.PaymentSystem, 
            p.ReceivedDate,    
            p.PropertyClassification, 
            p.ProjectImage,
            l.LocationName,
            pur.PurposeName,
            t.TypeName
    FROM dbo.Projects AS p 
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Locations AS l ON p.LocationID = l.ID      
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Purposes pur ON p.PurposeID = pur.ID 
    LEFT JOIN dbo.[Types] AS t ON p.TypeID = t.ID
    WHERE UPPER(ISNULL(l.LocationName,N'')) LIKE N'%' + UPPER(@location) + '%'
    OR UPPER(ISNULL(pur.PurposeName,N'')) LIKE N'%' + UPPER(@purpose) + '%'
    OR UPPER(ISNULL(t.TypeName,N'')) LIKE N'%' + UPPER(@type) + '%'
     )
GO


SELECT * FROM dbo.SearchProjects('','',''); -- Returns all records

SELECT * FROM dbo.SearchProjects('north',NULL,NULL); -- Returns all records with LocationName containing 'north'
SELECT * FROM dbo.SearchProjects(NULL,'research',NULL); -- Returns all records with PurposeName containing 'research'
SELECT * FROM dbo.SearchProjects(NULL,NULL,'closed'); -- Returns all records with TypeName containing 'closed'

SELECT * FROM dbo.SearchProjects('north','research',NULL); -- Returns all records with LocationName containing 'north' or PurposeName containing 'research'
```

`NULL`ing unwanted input parameters is necessary here because calling the function with an empty string in any of the input parameters would result in all records being returned:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.SearchProjects('north','','');
SELECT * FROM dbo.SearchProjects('north','research','');
SELECT * FROM dbo.SearchProjects('north','','closed');
```

Comment: it is worked thank very much, if you don't mind i want to contact with you on Skype or mail please .

Comment: Great, I'm glad you got the solution you were looking for. I don't hand out my contact details to people I don't know though I'm afraid - why did you want to email/Skype with me?

Comment: because i want to learn more from you and get more experience if you don't mind because i am beginner ?

Comment: I understand (I'm here to learn too!), but if you have more questions, just post them and then the whole SO community can help you, not just me (and trust me, there are literally thousands of others here much more knowledgable and experienced than I am).

Comment: ok, i want to add max and min for search criteria i want to insert max and min area for search criteria

Comment: If you have a new question, you should probably post a new question to ask it. Make sure you follow the guidelines on posting good questions so everyone can understand what problem you're having and what you've already tried. It shouldn't be too difficult to figure out how to add filters for a range of Area values (if these are numeric instead of text as in my example data) based on what you already have, so you need to give it a try yourself first and then post with specific problems when you run into them.

Answer (score 0):

The joins don't look right to me. You didn't fully specify your schema so I'm guessing, but it would be quite unusual to have a situation where those joins are used.

In this sample I changed the columns specified for each of the joins, but I was guessing what the columns might be named in your tables.

```
Alter FUNCTION SearchProjects (
    @location nvarchar(50),
    @purpose nvarchar(50),
    @type nvarchar(50))
 RETURNS TABLE
 AS
 RETURN
(
 SELECT p.ProjectName, 
     p.Areas, 
     p.PaymentSystem, 
     p.ReceivedDate,    
     p.PropertyClassification, 
     p.ProjectImage
  FROM dbo.Projects As p 
  LEFT JOIN dbo.Locations As l ON p.LocationID = l.ID      
  LEFT JOIN dbo.Purpose ON p.PurposeID = Purpose.ID 
  LEFT JOIN dbo.Types As t ON p.TypeID = t.ID
  WHERE (l.LocationName like N'%'+ @location +'%' 
         OR Purpose.PurposeName = N'%'+ @purpose +'%' 
         OR t.TypeName like N'%'+ @type     +'%')
 )
 GO

 SELECT * FROM dbo.SearchProjects('',' ','');
```

Sorry if I missed something in the question or comments that shows this is not the answer...

Comment: Doesn't this assume there is always a value in each of the `LocationId`, `PurposeId` and `TypeID` fields of the `Projects` table which matches a value in `Locations.ID`, `Purpose.ID` or `Types.ID` respectively? I think we should be using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` here instead of `INNER JOIN`. Unless [hashim](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6704418/hashim) can confirm there will always be records in each of the joined tables for any given record in `Projects`.

Comment: And the call `SELECT * FROM dbo.SearchProjects('',' ','');` will only return records where the associated PurposeName contains a space.

Comment: i update the question i changed the or operator  with and operator

Comment: @3N1GM4 yes their is records in each of joined tables

Comment: @hashim: specifically, for every value of `dbo.Projects.LocationID`, `dbo.Projects.PurposeID` and `dbo.Projects.TypeID`, there are records with matching values in `dbo.Locations.ID`, `dbo.Purposes.ID` and `dbo.Types.ID` respectively? i.e. every single project has a Location, Purpose and Type recorded against it and all recorded Locations, Purposes and Types exist in `dbo.Locations`, `dbo.Purposes` and `dbo.Types` respectively?

Comment: @3N1GM4 yes, for every value of  dbo.Projects.LocationID, dbo.Projects.PurposeID and dbo.Projects.TypeID ,there are records with matching values in dbo.Locations.ID, dbo.Purposes.ID and dbo.Types.ID ,every single project has Projects.LocationID,Projects.PurposeID,Projects.TypeID