# Create and execute function with more than parameters in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have four tables:

1-dbo.Projects(id,ProjectName,Areas,PaymentSystem,location.id,purpose.id,types.id,etc)

2-dbo.Locations (id, location name)

3-dbo.Purpose (id, Purposename)

4-dbo.Types (id, typname)

I have a search criteria, this criteria is filled with data from database tables: locations, purpose and  types, also have textboxes for max and min values.

I will search with all fields and max, min values - I reached to this query but missed the query to get or filter max and min :

```
ALTER FUNCTION SearchProjects (
@location NVARCHAR(50),
@purpose NVARCHAR(50),
@type NVARCHAR(50),
@max nvarchar(50),
@min nvarchar(50))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
  RETURN
  (
  SELECT  p.ProjectName, 
        p.Areas, 
        p.PaymentSystem, 
        p.ReceivedDate,    
        p.PropertyClassification, 
        p.ProjectImage,         
        l.LocationName,
        Pur.PurposeName,            
        t.TypeName
FROM dbo.Projects AS p 
LEFT JOIN dbo.Locations AS l ON p.LocationID = l.ID      
LEFT JOIN dbo.Purpose pur ON p.PurposeID = pur.ID 
LEFT JOIN dbo.[Types] AS t ON p.TypeID = t.ID
WHERE UPPER(ISNULL(l.LocationName,N'')) LIKE N'%' + UPPER(@location) + '%'
AND UPPER(ISNULL(pur.PurposeName,N'')) LIKE N'%' + UPPER(@purpose) + '%'
AND UPPER(ISNULL(t.TypeName,N'')) LIKE N'%' + UPPER(@type) + '%'
AND p.Areas like @max
AND p.Areas like @min
 )
 GO
SELECT * FROM dbo.SearchProjects('','','','200','250');
```

Comment: What are you asking ?  Please be specific.

Comment: I want to pass max and min values to function then return  filter on area column with the values , if i have in area column values from 100 to 300 in each records i want pass min value 100 and max value 200 then get all result matched with this values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create and execute function in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40719540/create-and-execute-function-in-sql-server)

Comment: @IvanStarostin no duplicate  the question is different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding you want filter for your `area` column for `max` and `min` value which you can achieve by using [BETWEEN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms187922.aspx)

```
AND p.Areas BETWEEN @min AND @max
```

So your `WHERE` condition will look something like,

```
WHERE 
    UPPER(ISNULL(l.LocationName,N'')) LIKE N'%' + UPPER(@location) + '%'
    AND UPPER(ISNULL(pur.PurposeName,N'')) LIKE N'%' + UPPER(@purpose) + '%'
    AND UPPER(ISNULL(t.TypeName,N'')) LIKE N'%' + UPPER(@type) + '%'
    AND p.Areas BETWEEN @min AND @max
```

Comment: i need something else when i call this line get all results :   SELECT FROM dbo.SearchProjects('','','','','');

Comment: if i do not pass min or max value get all results

Comment: @hashim That will happen as you are not passing anything to filter out data. If you need anything else in please specify in question with details.

Comment: ok, no i tried to select without passing values no result return